# Azure Media Services: LiveEventEndpoints of LiveEventInput purpose

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to set up live events in Azure Media Services. I already came across that issue, that output (streaming) URLs are only available after starting AND ingesting data into a live stream. But also the ingest URLs give me some headaches. I could define a ingest URL upfront, but that has to be static. And it is slower provisioned according to the docs.

But I found a class in the class hierarchy, that I am not sure, what it does. It is also not well documented: The **LiveEventInput** class accepts a List of "**LiveEventEndpoint**" as parameter. But I cannot figure out, what this LiveEventEndpoint really is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.liveeventendpoint?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.liveeventinput?view=azure-dotnet

All the code documentation as well as the API docs state something like "Gets or sets the input endpoints for the live event." But not *how* to use it and which protocols are allowed and what the URL should look like. Could somebody explain how this property should work? In my understanding I - of course - cannot simply define a custom ingest URL. Or is it the URL it should read the input stream from? I have **no** idea on how to understand that.

Comment: You are sending an HTTP Request and getting an HTTP Response which is the live data.  The request has parameters which can be either in the URL (usually after a question mark in the URL) or HTTP headers.  A Request/Response has a header and a body (the data contents). Microsoft Tries to simplify the Request/Response by creating library functions that does everything for you but often confuses the hell out of everybody by not giving important details.  The Request can contain parameters to specify the response data like XML or JSON.

Comment: The Microsoft Library has many different model types.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I still don't understand how this is supposed to work after your comment.

Comment: It is not documented very well.  There are two parameters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.liveeventendpoint.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Media_Models_LiveEventEndpoint__ctor_System_String_System_String_) a URL and a Protocol.  The library is a client and you need a server that is compatible with the library.  There is more info here but not much help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sdk-connection-string?tabs=net#syntax

Comment: This page has lots of examples : https://hund.io/help/documentation/live-event-streams

Answer (score 0):

You can create a live event with a static ingest by using a "static hostname prefix". This was called before "Vanity Url" mode. See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-events-outputs-concept#live-event-ingest-urls
Such live event has an ingest URL which is known before you start it.

Comment: Also, be sure to take a close look at the Live Sample. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/Live/LiveEventWithDVR